# Covariance between a variable and a non-linear transformation of it

Tags: random-variable, covariance, iid

Suppose $\epsilon \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} N(0, \sigma^2)$

Can we make any assumptions about Cov$(\epsilon, \frac{\epsilon^2}{1 + \epsilon^2})$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$cov(\epsilon,\frac{\epsilon^2}{1+\epsilon^2})=E[\frac{\epsilon^3}{1+\epsilon^2}]-E[\epsilon]E[\frac{\epsilon^2}{1+\epsilon^2}]$

$E[\epsilon] = 0$ and $E[\frac{\epsilon^3}{1+\epsilon^2}] = 0$ since we take the expectation of an odd function over a zero-mean normal RV.

So, it is 0.